# How to select only one column in simplecursoradapter and pass it another activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have a cursor in my main activity to query **two columns** of the database and display them using a simple cursor adapter.

```
private Cursor doQuery() {
return(db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT RestaurantID AS _id, RestaurantName, StoreNo "
+ "FROM RestaurantList ORDER BY RestaurantName", null));

}

public void onPostExecute() {
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_all_restaurants,
        doQuery(), new String[] {
    RestaurantDB.colRestaurantName,
    RestaurantDB.colRestaurantStore },
    new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.value },
    0);
}
else {
adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_all_restaurants,
        doQuery(), new String[] {
    RestaurantDB.colRestaurantName,
    RestaurantDB.colRestaurantStore },
    new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.value });
}

setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

What I want to do is that when the users click on a particular item, another activity will pop up giving the users more information, which means I need to display the data stored in **many other columns** of the same item too. My question is how I can do that. I thought I should use onListItemClick, but I don't know how to associate the item selected in the main activity to the new activity.

Also, in the main activity, I have two textviews in the list that display colRestaurantName and colRestaurantStore respectively. When I use onListItemClick, how can I just retrieve colRestaurantName?

I can do the following to retrieve the position, but I don't know how I can use it in the new activity:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
    long id){
Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getCursor();
selection = String.valueOf(c.getPosition());
Intent i = new Intent(AllRestaurants.this, RestaurantsInfo.class);
i.putExtra("restaurantSelection", selection);
startActivity(i);      
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement `onListItemClick` for listview and get textview text and send it to next activity as:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
       TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
      String strcolRestaurantName=tv.getText().toString();

      Intent intent =new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("RestaurantName",strcolRestaurantName);
      intent.putExtras(bundle);
      startActivity(intent);
}}
```

and in NextActivity get Intent as in  onCreate :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

String strRestaurantName = extras.getString("RestaurantName");
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I will figure out the rest.